# python RegDeleteKey error 5 access denied

Tags: python, python-2.7, pywin32

I took the following python recipe from Activestate.org, then I simply added the method for deleting the key, however I getting error 5, access denied, and the key it's only a fake key which I have just created to try out the function . Here 's the code

```
## {{{ http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576860/ (r2)
import win32api
import win32con

def regquerysubkeys(handle, key, keylist=[]):

#get registry handle
    reghandle = win32api.RegOpenKeyEx(handle, key, 0, win32con.KEY_ALL_ACCESS)    
    try:
        i = 0
    #enumerates subkeys and recursively calls this function again
        while True:
            subkey = win32api.RegEnumKey(reghandle, i)
            #the following is the line I added myself
            win32api.RegDeleteKey(handle, key)


            i += 1
        #braintwister here ;-)
            regquerysubkeys(handle, key + subkey + "\\", keylist)
    except win32api.error as ex:
        #If no more subkeys can be found, we can append ourself
        if ex[0] == 259:
            keylist.append(key)
        #unexpected exception is raised
        else:
            raise
    finally:
    #do some cleanup and close the handle
        win32api.RegCloseKey(reghandle)
#returns the generated list
    print keylist

#call to the function
regquerysubkeys(win32con.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "SOFTWARE\\suga\\")
```

Those are the errors I m getting in the console.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\EclipseWorkspaces\csse120\MMS-auto\test1.py", line 34, in <module>
regquerysubkeys(win32con.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "SOFTWARE\\suga\\")
File "C:\EclipseWorkspaces\csse120\MMS-auto\test1.py", line 14, in regquerysubkeys
win32api.RegDeleteKey(handle, key)
pywintypes.error: (5, 'RegDeleteKey', 'Access is denied.')
```

Can anyone help out with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you running 64-bit Windows 7 by any chance?  There were some changes in the structure of the registry to account for running both 32-bit and 64-bit programs that require that you use different APIs for deletion.  [The `RegDeleteKey` Win32 API documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724845%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) mentions using `RegDeleteKeyEx` in some cases.  The Win32 API is difficult to use reliably from one major version of Windows to the next.  Unfortunately, `pywin32` does its best to hide a number of the headaches, but it still requires that you really know the Win32 API and its caveats before you can effectively use it.

Comment: I have read that in the documentation, however I'm running windowXp 32bit, therefore I though I shouldn't have that kind of problem.

Comment: Strange, but switch off antiviral software fix same issue in my case.